# Linq expression IEnumerable<TEntity> does not contain definition of where

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-programming

How to write correct Linq expression used in generic for condition "where"

```
public static class ConStr
{
    public static MySqlConnection Conn()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCN"].ConnectionString);
    }

}
```

Repositor.cs

```
private IDbConnection cn;

public IEnumerable<TEntity> FilterBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
     using(cn = ConStr.Conn())
     {
        return cn.GetAll<TEntity>(null).Where(expression); <--error does not contain definition of where
     }

 }
```

but this with Linq expression will run

```
using (IDbConnection cn = ConStr.Conn()) 
{
    var que = cn.GetAll<Cause>(null).Where(x=>x.cause_id == 1);            
    bool dbIE = Utils.IsAny<Cause>(que);
    if (dbIE == true)
    {
        DGRID.DataSource = que;
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry No Value");
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your `GetAll` is returning `IEnumerable<T>` which does not have `Where` with `Expression`, but `Func`. Visually there is no difference between  implicit `Expression<Func<...>>` and `Func<...>`, that's why your second snippet compiles.

Comment: Instead of implementing IEnumerable you can put all items in a List Collection.  A List Collection is IEnumerable so you don't have to write you own implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev ah I see thanks a lot I will try to change

Comment: Note your `FilterAll` method will most likely not work given that the connection is closed by the time you return the `IQueryable<T>` implementation.

Comment: @casperOne this depends on how `GetAll` extension implemented

Comment: @casperOne opps I forgot Im using Dapper the GetAll() is in Dapper Extension

Comment: @maxim see this previous version which my comment was based on: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36810185/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Where` for `IEnumerable<T>` does not contains overload that takes `Expression`. To use `Where` with `Expression` you must change the result of `GetAll` to `IQueryable`. For your particular case you can just change `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression` to `Func<TEntity, bool> expression` and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks so Func<TEntity, bool> expression -> is for IEnumerable<T> and for is for IQueryable<T> is -> Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression.

Comment: There is also `AsQueryable()` extension on `IEnumerable<T>` type which casts your `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable`, but I don't really know why would you want to use this in production..Most of the time simple `Func` or `Action` would be enough and if you want to use `Expression` you need to know why